# Finding paragraphs with only &nbsp; and removing the p tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to find all p tags with inline style attrs style="text-align:center;" that contain just `&nbsp;` and nothing else. And then removing the entire p for each found.

There are other p tags with the same attr that contain more than just nbsp which I want to keep, Im just stuck on finding the ones with a space only. Stupid wordpress tinyMCE editor, drives me nuts.

This is the base of what i was working on doing it with. just outputs all the text-align center p tags.

```
var p = $('.entry p[style="text-align: center;"]');
p.each(function() { 
  console.log(p);
});
```

Stupid little thing, i dont want to spend anymore time trying to figure out what im doing wrong. Here's an example page that has the stuff im working with.
http://www.drinkinginamerica.com/page/14/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `remove()` function:

```
$('.entry p').each(function() {
    var $p = $(this),
        txt = $p.html();
    if (txt=='&nbsp;') {
        $p.remove();   
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/LJHyA/ for a working example. This assumes a pretty strict case in which the only thing in the `p` tag is the `&nbsp;` entity.

---

Too slow - @mu wins.

Comment: You left out the `style` attribute filtering but the `$(this).html() == '&nbsp;'` is the main thing.

Comment: this works, thanks. i was going to use the remove() method but couldnt get it to single out the nbsp p tags. was trying too hard to do it in 1 line

Comment: @mu - I guess I was assuming that we probably wanted to axe all `p` tags that only contained `&nbsp;`, regardless of style, but of course the selector could be adjusted if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
$('.entry p[style="text-align: center;"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().match(/^\s*&nbsp;\s*$/))
        $this.remove();
});
```

This is a bit sensitive to the precise `style` attribute but somewhat forgiving on how the the `&nbsp;` is formatting inside the paragraphs.

I think something a bit looser might serve you better:

```
$('.entry p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.css('text-align') == 'center'
    && $this.html().match(/^\s*&nbsp;\s*$/))
        $this.remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nMKnR/